# Cannot return subclass object to generic superclass return type in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have to implement a method where I have a SuperClass (which is generic) as a return type and I have to return a particular subclass(which is not generic) Object.
My method signature being

```
private <A extends ClassA<B>, B>  SuperClass<A,B>  methodA(){
   subclass sc = new subclass();
   return sc;
}
```

compiler complains as cannot convert subclass to SuperClass;

if I typecast it to SuperClass, it gives me warning as Uncheckedcast from subclass to SuperClass

Another way I tried doing it is

```
private <SC extends SuperClass<A,B>, A extends ClassA<B>, B> SC methodA(){
   subclass sc = new subclass();
   return sc;
}
```

it still gives me the same error:cannot convert from subclass to SC.

finally I tried this

```
private <SC extends SuperClass<A,B>, A extends ClassA<B>, B> SC methodA(){
   SC sc = (SC)new subclass();
   return sc;
}
```

and now have a warning unchecked cast.

My subclass declaration

```
 subclass extends SuperClass<ClassC, ClassD>
 where ClassC extends ClassA and ClassD is a concrete type.
```

My superclass declaration

```
 class SuperClass<A extends ClassA<B>, B>
```

Can anybody please tell me why we cannot return a subtype object to a generic superclass and why there is no warning free way of doing it?

Comment: Can you add the class headers of both Superclass and Subclass(es)?

Comment: Does ClassC extend ClassA <ClassD> ? If not you are breaking the allowable bounds of SuperClass in SubClass.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make sense. Presumably, `subclass` extends `SuperClass` with particular parameters, or else it would be generic itself. (Or it could inherit from the raw version, which is logically equivalent to passing `Object` for both parameters.)

This means that `subclass` can be safely converted to `SuperClass` with those particular parameters. Converting it to any other version of `SuperClass` is just wrong.

The compiler is telling you that your code is wrong, and the compiler is right. Rethink your design.

Edit to clarify:

Let's assume I have code like this:

```
public class ClassE {}
public class ClassF extends ClassA<ClassE> {}

SuperClass<ClassF, ClassE> sc = someobject.<ClassF, ClassE>methodA();
```

Now this code would compile, because it has correct types. But if your code didn't produce errors or warnings, then `sc` would now point to a `subclass`, which doesn't extend `SuperClass<ClassF, ClassE>`, it extends `SuperClass<ClassC, ClassD>`, which is different. It's simply wrong to want this code to work.

I suspect you have an XY problem going on here. What is the problem you actually want to solve? Because the solution you started on isn't working.

Comment: yes my subclass extends SuperClass with subclasses of A and B. declaration goes as
subclass extends SuperClass<C,D>
where C extends A and D is a concrete type.